# Fetch Data from API with authenticate from Serivcenow

Tags: react-native

I am having problem fetching data from API to post in my app. The API I use is from ServiceNow platform but before I get a data I have to authenticate into my API. I did this code and got stuck with it.

I coded this part and got stuck in authentication and getting the data from API to post into the home screen

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ionic" style={{ fontsize: 24, color: tintColor }} />
    )
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("https://service-now.com/api/now/table/table_name_here", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: "myUserName",
        password: "myPassword"
      })
    })
      .then(results => results.JSON())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header style={{ backgroundColor: "#e6e6fa" }}>
          <Left>
            <Icon
              name="menu"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
            />
          </Left>
          <Body style={{ alignItems: "right" }}>
            <Title>Home Page</Title>
          </Body>
        </Header>

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.ListItem}>{}</Text>
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [ServiceNow](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/document/content/app_store_doc_rest_integrate_jakarta_c_RESTAPISecurity?v=madrid) uses basic authentication for its table REST api. Instead of passing the username and password in the body of your fetch call, try including an Authorization header:

```
fetch('https://service-now.com/api/now/table/table_name_here', {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)
});
```